# Changing velocity even when acceleration is zero

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, coordinate-systems, velocity

Consider a particle performing circular motion with position given by
$$\vec r=r_0e^{\beta t}\hat r$$ such that $\dot\theta=\omega$, is a constant.

The velocity becomes
$$\vec v=\beta r_0e^{\beta t}\hat r+r_0\omega e^{\beta t}\hat\theta$$
And acceleration
$$\vec a=(\beta^2r_0e^{\beta t}-\omega^2r_0e^{\beta t})\hat r+2r_0\beta\omega e^{\beta t}\hat\theta$$
If $\beta=\pm\omega$, then $a_r=0$ but $v_r\neq 0$

I am not able to physically understand the cause for this.

Comment: Did you take the time derivatives of $\hat{r}$ and $\hat{\theta}$ to get the acceleration? (I haven't yet done the calculation, so I can't tell if you've taken that into account or not.)

Comment: Also, if the post is correct, and $r=r_0e^{\beta t}$, then this problem isn't completely defined, because this says that $r$ changes exponentially with time, but doesn't explain at all how $\theta$ and $\phi$ change with time.  On the other hand, if you actually meant $\vec{r} = \vec{r}_0e^{\beta t}$, then this corresponds to straight-line motion along the direction $\vec{r}_0$. Can you clarify?

Comment: Your formula for acceleration has *two* terms, only one of which disappears when $\beta = \pm \omega$.

Comment: @march yes I have taken their derivatives and actually, we don't need to know the dependence of angle for calculation since we only need to know that theta is not a constant for taking the derivatives, for reference this problem is an example number 1.19 of second edition of Kleppner and Kolenkow

Comment: @EricSmith yes but i am specifically talking about radial acceleration and velocity as mentioned in the post

Comment: So if the $\theta$ dependence isn't specified, why is there no $\dot{\theta}$  hanging around?

Comment: @march derivative of r hat dot = theta dot (that is omega) theta dot  and derivative of theta hat = - omega r hat

Comment: Okay that makes sense, although it would be helpful to add these clarifications to your your post. In addition, it *seems* as if you are assuming that $\dot{\theta}=\omega$ is a *constant*, since the $\ddot{\theta}$ term is missing. Is this correct? Or are you wondering about the situation in which $\beta=\omega=\dot{\theta}$ at some single point in time?

Comment: Okay, also, wait a minute: you've changed your post. I think the original version of your post was closer to what you're asking, because $\vec{r}=\vec{r}_0e^{\beta t}$ has no circular component: it just corresponds to motion along a line, whereas $r=r_0e^{\beta t}$, while underspecified, at least allows for $\theta$ to change.

Comment: @march yes omega is a constant sorry for not specifying that I'll make it correct in the post too, also the formula for r written in the updated post is the correct one since if r was a constant, omega would be zero and this post would make no sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136522/discussion-between-gedankenexperimentalist-and-march).